# Fade In jquery image overlappes my Fixed Header

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, sticky, overlapping

This is the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#showhidetarget').hide();

        $('a#showhidetrigger').click(function () {
            $('#showhidetarget').toggle(150);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my sticky header nav CSS

```
#nav {
    background-color: #001f22;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
```

Nav Html

```
  <div id="nav"><ul>
         <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
         <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Fade-in CSS

```
.fade {
   opacity: 0.5;
   transition: opacity .50s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity .50s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .50s ease-in;
   }

   .fade:hover {
    opacity: 1;
      }

   .fade:visited {
    opacity: 1;

      }
```

So basically, my fade-in/fade-out jquery images OVERLAP/go in front, of the fixed nav bar. How do i fix this so it doesn't overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the NAV bar a z-index and also to the fadeIn objects.

Make sure the NAV bar has a higher z-index, for exmaple.

```
.fade {
   opacity: 0.5;
   transition: opacity .50s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity .50s ease-in;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .50s ease-in;
   z-index: 10;
   }

#nav {
    background-color: #001f22;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: No problem, enjoy the coding.

Answer (score 1):

You now about the css-property "z-index"?
z-index controlls wich element will be shown on top. An Element with a bigger z-index will overlap an element with a lower z-index.

So set the z-index for the header e.g. to 999:

```
#nav {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

And the z-index for the images to something below.

Hope that helps.

Comment: z-index works only if the element to apply is positioned relative, absolute or fixed and is display: inline-block or display: block. If your images are not positioned now, use position:relative which will not move the images instead of e.g. position:absolute;